# Fetch data (json) from Prestashop's Rest API in Javascript ES6 (React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, rest, fetch, prestashop-1.7

I'm hunting for a solution this problem. I want to use the prestashop REST API for a specific test activity. My problem is that I can not authenticate with this form and not even using buffer and DOMParser because I am working on a project for android 4.4.1 and Buffer is not compatible.

Could anyone help? Thank you in advance. Best Regards.

I did something like this (two examples below):

```
let API = null;
const SERVER_ADDRESS = 'http://192.168.1.5/prestashop/api/';
```

//also tried with "&output_format=JSON"
    const token = 'X3IIMEP8JJI3PKPXIMEP8JJI3PKPICJMM';

```
try {
    fetch(SERVER_ADDRESS, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': token
        }
    })    
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.status == 200) return response.json();
        else throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.debug(response);
        // ...
    })
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

========================

```
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';
import {DOMParser} from 'xmldom';

let API = null;
const SERVER_ADDRESS = 'http://192.168.1.5/prestashop/api/';
const REST = {
    CMS: 'content_management_system'
};
const token = 'XGRCBUW745EH4SPHCU92MKL4RGNVPYXY';
const AuthorizationString = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(token + ':').toString('Base64');

try {

    componentDidMount({
    fetch(SERVER_ADDRESS, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': AuthorizationString
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        response.text().then(function (text) {
            API = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text);
        });
    });

    }

} 

catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
    }
```

I am not sure about how prestashop does their auth but my system uses JWT and requires the token to be prefixed with `Bearer`

Comment: I gonna try! But i'm using the "Advanced REST client" (Chrome ext) to get the headers form it gives something like: 
HTTP headers: "authorization" pass: "Basic VFc2RjUxQUHAJHSIIPEO28CS978D3N9DN02U0U1ZZS0k6VFc2RjUxQU".
Inside my aplication a use this Basic string as a const to my fetch header.

Comment: generally, Bearer is used for token based authentication. Basic is if the client is sending username/password type credentials.